# Как собрать PyQt5-программу в APK-файл для установки на Android?

Tags: python, android, pyqt5, apk

Имеется `Python` программа на `PyQt5`. Недавно появилась необходимость запустить ее на `Android`-устройстве. Для этого использую приложение [`Pydroid 3`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iiec.pydroid3&hl=ru&gl=US). Все отлично запускается, отображается и работает. Выглядит как полноценное приложение под Android, но не всегда удобно для запуска лезть в `Pydroid` и искать нужный мне код.

Хочется вывести какой-то ярлык для запуска, или вообще **собрать этот код в полноценное приложение**.

---

В гугле по запросу "*[pyqt5 to android apk](https://www.google.com/search?q=pyqt5%20to%20android%20apk&ei=-ED3YIr6J5eTwPAP3Le9kAs&oq=pyqt5%20to%20android%20apk&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEBYQHjoHCAAQRxCwA0oECEEYAFDRBViCC2D2D2gBcAJ4AIABfYgB2QSSAQMwLjWYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiK1ojZzPLxAhWXCRAIHdxbD7IQ4dUDCA4&uact=5)*" я нашел информацию разве что об инструменте `pyqtdeploy`, но по факту, ни на *YouTube*, ни в *документации* я либо не нашел вообще, либо не нашел понятной для себя инструкции.

---

**В идеале, хотелось бы получить в качестве ответа подробную инструкцию - может кто-то уже собирал `PyQt5` в `APK`? Или хотя бы получить сслыку на какой-нибудь пошаговый гайд.**

*`Kivy` не использую, потому что не хочется переучиваться с `PyQt5`. Пока я чувствую возможность сборки в `APK` из `PyQt5`, я не готов переходить на что-то другое*

Comment: вот тут посмотрите  https://wiki.qt.io/PySide_for_Android_guide

Comment: На kivy можешь перейти, но компиляция в apk это гемор ещё тот. Да к тому же kivy выглядит старовато, а kivymd, который поновее, в apk не компилируется. Он будет просто вылетать при запуске на Android

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.org/project/pyqtdeploy/ библиотека для конвертирования
https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/pyqtdeploy/ дока этой библиотеки